# app.shell_context_processor decorator no registra la función como una función de contexto de shell

Tags: shell, flask

Creé la siguiente función en un archivo `microblog.py`. Crea un contexto de shell que agrega una instancia de base de datos y modelos a la sesión de shell:

```
from app import app, db
from app.models import User, Post

@app.shell_context_processor
def make_shell_context():
    return {'db': db, 'User': User, 'Post': Post}
```

El decodificador `app.shell_context_processor` registra la función como una función de contexto de shell. Pero cuando se ejecuta el comando del mazo del matraz, no invoca esta función y registra los elementos devueltos por él en la sesión de shell como se esperaba.

Así que me sale esto:

```
(MyFlaskAppEnv) mike@mike-thinks:~/Programing/Rasa/myflaskapp$ flask shell
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 23 2017, 16:37:01) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
App: app [production]
Instance: /home/mike/Programing/Rasa/myflaskapp/instance
>>> db
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'db' is not defined
```

En lugar de eso:

```
(venv) $ flask shell
>>> db
<SQLAlchemy engine=sqlite:////Users/migu7781/Documents/dev/flask/microblog2/app.db>
```